# Java: Database check and initialization

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, db-schema

I'm writing a Java application that uses SQLite via JDBC for persistence.

What I need to do when the application starts is:

1. If the DB doesn't exists, create it with the right schema
2. If the DB exists, check if the DB has the right schema

In order to create the DB I thought of externalizing the SQL commands needed to create the structure (e.g. CREATE TABLE ...) in an external file, load it at runtime and execute it.
I thought of using `BufferedReader` with `.readLine()` and then feed each SQL command to a `Statement.executeUpdate()`. Is there some smarter way to do this?

Concerning the startup check of the database schema, while I think that this should be considered "good design", I don't know if in practice it could be overkill or useless.
One solution I came up with but has the disadvantage of being "vendor dependent" is this:

1. Create the DB by using a known prefix for all the structures' names (e.g. `nwe_`)
2. Query the `sqlite_master` table with `WHERE name LIKE 'nwe_%'`
3. Compare the content of the `SQL` column with the SQL command file I used for creating the DB

Again, is there some smarter way to do this? (maybe not "vendor dependent", but this at the time is not much of an issue for me)

Thanks.

Comment: In regards to your first question, I don't see how reading in a text file of SQL commands is any different than putting those same SQL commands in a `static final String`. You have to write out the SQL somewhere; what do you gain by having it outside of your code?

Comment: In regards to your second question, what is your use case where your DB schema is magically different from the one you created initially and have been using throughout your program?

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot 1-: I'm not a big fan of hardcoded strings because, for one, if you need to change the content of the strings you have to rebuild the application. Am I wrong?
2-: Maybe the DB is corrupted or the user makes the application to point to a wrong DB file.

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot I'm a n00b too, that's why I'm "asking the experts". :) To be honest, I can't think of anything to reply to your comment. Maybe if I were to add some initialization data after creating the schema, that would have sense. But now, except for testing purposes, I don't think I could ever need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write up your own verification of the database by looking in the metdata tables.  This is not impossible, but it is a lot of code to maintain.  You can also write up a lot of DDL statements to construct the database structures, again not impossible, but a lot of code to maintain.

If you follow such a path, I recommend a higher-level logic of

```
if (!checkDatabase()) {
  try {
    if (wantsToInstall()) {
      installDatabase();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    exit();
  }
}
```

or a specific installer (to reduce the chance of installing over existing items).  Extensions that provide deleting data items can be done, but there are differing opinions as to what to do if encountering an unexpected pre-existing object during install / upgrade.

Now there are a few libraries that will do this for you; but by the time they add this feature, such a library probably takes care of *much more* than simple database structure maintenance.  Look to JDO and a few others, I know that DataNucleus's environment will gladly create database structures tweaked to work well in just over 20 different databases (remember they all have subtle differences in how they do things).

Comment: Do you think that it's worth the effort to implement a `checkDatabase()`? Is this good design?
Concerning the `installDatabase()` part, what do you think about hardcoded SQL vs. external file?

Comment: Do you want to install tables blind?  Without a check, how will you know when you are dealing with a previous release of your own database?  As far as "hardcoded SQL", if you go that route, then try to make it semi-portable; because, one day they'll want it on an unsupported database.  If using an external file, why even bother two write Java code?  You need to evaluate your customer needs, balance the work effort with ease of use, and decide what is best for them.

Comment: I need to write Java code to read from the file and then execute the SQL statements. How could I be able to execute them, otherwise?
Accessing metadata as far as I know breaks portability. I don't know how else to check the DB.
Thank you.

Comment: Accessing meta data does not break portability, it enhances portability.  Without fetching the JDBC metadata object, how do you know if your database supports a particular type, or if one of your columns conflicts with a keyword (added in through a SQL Extension)?  If your Java only reads a file and runs the command, why not just run the file from the database console?  You have decided on a solution before you have thought about the problem.  That's a premature solution.  If I have the SQL available, why would I even need / want your program?

Comment: I'm sorry but I realize that my level of knowledge isn't enough to understand your answer. Thanks anyway.
I'll accept your answer and give a +1 for your effort.

Comment: That's ok.  Basically there are no "standard" databases, so the meta data allows you to look for the specific features your program needs, and if the feature doesn't exist, then you "activate" a chunk of code to implement the "workaround".  This means that your program, using the metadata object, becomes _more_ portable, because it doesn't assume that each database works the same way (which will make it break as soon as it encounters a database that works differently).  Core SQL is the same for SQL databases, but the SQL extensions effectively make all databases different.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a professional programmer and this is my first java application, but I decided to do
database verification too.
Fortunately, sqlite databases has a system table with sql statements for each table in database.
So there is a fast and dirty way to check database structure:

```
public class Model {
    private Map<String, String> tableSql;

    Model(){
        // declare right database's tables syntax 
        tableSql = new HashMap<String, String>();
        tableSql.put("settings",    "CREATE TABLE [settings] ( [id]     INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [item] ... )");
        tableSql.put("scheta",      "CREATE TABLE [scheta] ( [id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [sname] ...)");
        tableSql.put("nomera",      "CREATE TABLE [nomera] ( [id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [nvalue] ...)");
        tableSql.put("corr",        "CREATE TABLE [corr] (  [id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [cname] ...)");
        tableSql.put("category",    "CREATE TABLE [category] ( [id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [cname] ...)");
        tableSql.put("price",       "CREATE TABLE [price] ( [id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [cdate] ...)");
    }

    public void Connect( String path){
        File DBfile = new File (path);
        boolean DBexists = DBfile.exists();
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs;

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + path);
            c.setAutoCommit(true);

            stmt = c.createStatement();
            if( DBexists ){
                // check database structure
                for (String tableName : tableSql.keySet()) {
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = '" + tableName + "'");
                    if(rs.isBeforeFirst()){
                        rs.next();
                        // table and field names may be inside square brackets or inside quotes...
                        String table_schema_there = rs.getString(1).replaceAll("\\s+"," ").replaceAll("[\\[\\]'`]", "\"");
                        String table_schema_here = tableSql.get(tableName).replaceAll("\\s+"," ").replaceAll("[\\[\\]'`]", "\"");;
                        if( ! table_schema_there.equals(table_schema_here) ){
                            notifyListeners( new ModelResponse( false, "Structure error. Wrong structure of table "  + tableName));
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        notifyListeners( new ModelResponse( false, "Structure error. The table is missing: "  + tableName ));
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                // empty DB file created during connection so we need to create schema
                for (String tableName : tableSql.keySet()) {
                    stmt.executeUpdate(tableSql.get(tableName));
                }
            }
        } 
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            notifyListeners( new ModelResponse( false, e.getMessage()));
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```